# Custom Authorization in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

I'm looking for some guidance on where/how best to implement custom Authorization logic in an Asp.Net Core 6.0 API app.

I have some very custom authorization logic to implement, including sometimes needing to get data needed to make authorization decisions from the DB.

All the reading I've done seems to be telling me I should either implement a custom subclass of AuthorizeAttribute or implement a custom policy.  The  overhead involved in understanding these two options and then comparing them seems ... significant.  And even then, anyone on my team who is going to work on authorization will need the same level of understanding.  This feels like a pretty big lift and ongoing tax for something that seems like it could be done pretty simply.

The simple solution I'm talking about is to simply make a function call to check authorization as the first line in the controller code and return 4xx. Something like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    public string Edit() {
        if(!IsAuthorizedToEdit()) return 4xx response; 
        //Continue with functional logic 
    }
}
```

My question is - what am I losing by taking this simple (also easily understandable and maintainable) approach ? What are the risks and what problems might I run into? I'm not overly experienced with Asp.net, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: IS IsAuthorizedToEdit() a action that [Authorized] Attribute attched to ?

Comment: No, I had intended IsAuthorizedToEdit() to be a standalone method, not attached to any attribute or policy